# Probability of a series of events

Tags: probability

I have 5 hammers to break into a safe with.

- There's a 95% chance I will fail to open the safe.
- There's a 70% chance that upon failure I will loose a hammer.

Whats the probability of opening the safe?

What I know for each turn at opening the safe:

- It's a 66.5% chance that I will fail and loose a hammer.
- It's a 38.5% chance that I will fail but retain a hammer.
- It's a 5% chance that I will open the safe.

Answer (score 1):

Let us calculate the probability of breaking the first hammer; I presume you can take it from there.

We have, given the initial situation, probability $0.95 \times 0.70$ to lose a hammer. Furthermore, we have a probability of $0.95 \times 0.30$ to return to the initial state, and try again.

Therefore, the chance to break the first hammer is given by the following geometric series:

$$(0.95 \times 0.70) \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (0.95 \times 0.30)^n = \frac{0.95 \times 0.70}{1-0.95\times 0.30} \approx 0.93007$$

The exact number is (should it be of interest) $\dfrac{133}{143}$.

Comment: Ok if that's the probability of breaking the first hammer, how do we expand that out to see the probability of succeeding with only 5 hammers?  Would you just multiply them out like a series of independent events?

Comment: Yes, they're independent. So the probability of succeeding is $1$ minus the probability of breaking all five of them.